# subdomain for redmine via terminal

Tags: apache, subdomain, redmine

I installed redmine on a virtual server (Ubuntu 10.04) with this tutorial:
[install guide](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_Install_Redmine_in_Ubuntu) 
Everything seems to be correct, where I stuck is how to make my redmine installation accessible from browser or in other words how to add a subdomain to the existing.

The virtual Server is available under:

```
lvps46-163-79-1.dedicated.hosteurope.de
```

which points to a standard htdocs directory.(/var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs/)

My Redmine installation is under:
/usr/share/redmine/

I tried to setup a subdomain with plesk as written in the tut but this failed. Is there an easy (understandable for beginners) way by terminal to make the installation available under:

```
redmine.lvps46-163-79-117.dedicated.hosteurope.de
```

Kind regards,

toni

Answer (score 0):

Just to make this complete. I followed the instructions with the apache doku. Unfortunately I couldn´t get the vhost working. I´m now using Mongrel Server on Port 3000 which works for me.